# R: trim consecutive trailing and leading special characters from set of strings

Tags: r, character

I have a list of character vectors, all equal lengths. Example data:

```
> a = list('**aaa', 'bb*bb', 'cccc*')
> a = sapply(a, strsplit, '')
> a
[[1]]
[1] "*" "*" "a" "a" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "b" "*" "b" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "c" "c" "c" "*"
```

I would like to identify the indices of all leading and trailing **consecutive** occurrences of the character `*`. Then I would like to remove these indices from **all three vectors** in the list. By trailing and leading consecutive characters I mean e.g. either only a single occurrence as in the third one (`cccc*`) or multiple consecutive ones as in the first one (`**aaa`).

After the removal, all three character vectors should still have the same length.

So the first two and the last character should be removed from **all three vectors**.

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "*" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "c"
```

Note that the second vector of the desired result will still have a leading `*`, which, however became the first character after the operation, so it should be in.

I tried using `which` to identify the indices (`sapply(a, function(x)which(x=='*'))`) but this would still require some code to detect the trailing ones.

Any ideas for a simple solution?

Comment: Why did you remove some of the letters?

Comment: Tried to clarify the question: If I find in one of the strings, at the beginning or the end one or more, `*`'s, I want to remove these indices from all of the strings. So if one of the strings is `**a**`, I want to remove index `1,2,4,5` from this string and all other strings.

Comment: try `i1 <- unlist(gregexpr('(?<=\\*)\\*|\\*(?=\\*)|^\\*|\\*$', unlist(a), perl=TRUE));i2 <- setdiff(seq(nchar(a[[1]])), i1[i1>0]); strsplit(substr(unlist(a), i2[1], i2[2]), '')`

Comment: This gives me a list of fifteen `character(0)`

Comment: I got the expected output as showed in your post.  BTW, I used `a <- list('**aaa', 'bb*bb', 'cccc*')`

Comment: @akrun: I see, it works for me if I apply it to the list of strings and not the list of character vectors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace the lead and lag stars with `NA`:

```
aa <- lapply(setNames(a,seq_along(a)), function(x) {
  star = x=="*"
  toNA = cumsum(!star) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(!star))) == 0
  replace(x, toNA, NA)
})
```

Store in a data.frame:

```
DF <- do.call(data.frame, c(aa, list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) )
```

Omit all rows with `NA`:

```
res <- na.omit(DF)
#   X1 X2 X3
# 3  a  *  c
# 4  a  b  c
```

---

If you hate data.frames and want your list back: `lapply(res,I)` or `c(unclass(res))`, which gives

```
$X1
[1] "a" "a"

$X2
[1] "*" "b"

$X3
[1] "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, like Richard Scriven asked in his comment to your question, your output is not the same as the thing you asked for. You ask for removal of leading and trailing characters, but your given ideal output is just the 3rd and 4th element of the character lists.
This would be easily achievable by something like

```
a <- list('**aaa', 'bb*bb', 'cccc*')
alist = sapply(a, strsplit, '')
lapply(alist, function(x) x[3:4])
```

Now for an answer as you asked it:

IMHO, `sapply()` isn't necessary here.
You need a function of the grep family to operate directly on your characters, which all share a help page in R opened by ?grep.

I would propose `gsub()` and a bit of Regular Expressions for your problem:

```
a <- list('**aaa', 'bb*bb', 'cccc*')
b <- gsub(pattern = "^(\\*)*", x = a, replacement = "")
c <- gsub(pattern = "(\\*)*$", x = b, replacement = "")
> c
[1] "aaa"   "bb*bb" "cccc"
```

This is doable in one regex, but then you need a backreference for the stuff in between i think, and i didn't get this to work.

If you are familiar with the magrittr package and its excellent pipe operator, you can do this more elegantly:

```
library(magrittr)
gsub(pattern = "^(\\*)*", x = a, replacement = "") %>%
gsub(pattern = "(\\*)*$", x = ., replacement = "")
```

Comment: My understanding is that the `sapply` is simply used to construct the example data, described as "a list of character vectors".

Comment: @Frank: True, this is just a simple toy example to resemble my real data. I have no preference if list or dataframe, a list of character vectors was just what came out of the package I was using.

Comment: @zerwck: This does not work for me, all resulting strings should have the same lengths...